# Link model parts and create proxies with modifers applied

Tags: python, rigging

I'm using Blender 2.8 and I'm trying to setup a pipeline for modeling, rigging, and animating in different but linked files.

The characters I am creating are modular so I want to keep the pieces separate and I would like to keep modifiers (like mirror modifiers) unapplied in the model file.

I have a script that links the model collection from the model file into the rigging file. Then it creates a new collection containing a proxy for each object in the linked collection and parents it to the armature with automatic weights.

Unfortunately the proxies do not seem to carry the modifiers with them so some of the pieces which are mirrored I am only getting half of them.

Is there a way to achieve this? I can't think of way to get it to work besides appending in the model and applying the modifiers in the rigging file but then it will no longer be linked.

I'm basically looking at steps 1 and 2 of [this](https://download.blender.org/institute/nodes-design/pipeline.html).

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Further to this, If I could actually get the proxies in with modifiers I still wouldn't be able to weight paint in a second file would I? As even with a proxy the mesh data cannot be edited unless it is made local. 

I don't see an option now besides having the model and rig in one file.

Comment: Further further to this. I created a blend with rig and model and linked it an animation blend file. I made a proxy to the armature and started animating. I noticed the IK was off on one arm so I fixed it in the original model/rig file but it seems that doesn't carry across. It looks like all the constraints are now local to the animation file so I would need to manually apply those constraints. I can't find any decent information on this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay I've fixed the above issue by using protected layers. Now when I change constraints they are propagated. [See](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxlFSDXkn6Y)